# How to split a math formula that is composed of variables that contain dashes

Tags: python, regex, split

Trying to split this line:

```
formula='%abc-def%+%hij-klm%/%opq+rst%-%uvw-xyz%
```

The variable are contained with the `"%"` signs and must remain intact.

I want to split on `+-/*` without splitting the variable due to the `'-'` in the name.

Is there an easy way without having to use a for loop to scan each character?

---

**1st Way:**

Splits the variables (no good):

```
re.compile("[\+\/\-\*]").split(formula) 

['%abc', 'def%', '%hij', 'klm%', '%opq', 'rst%', '%uvw', 'xyz%']
```

---

**2nd Way:**

Loses the % (no good):

```
re.compile("%[\+\/\-\*]%").split(formula) 

['%abc-def', 'hij-klm', 'opq+rst', 'uvw-xyz%']
```

---

**Expected Output:**

I'm looking for something that'll yield:

```
['%abc-def%', '%hij-klm%', '%opq+rst%', '%uvw-xyz%']
```

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Will there ever be other `%` characters in the string or are they only allowed around variables?

Comment: THey are only allowed around variables.

Comment: If you're going to expand to a more complex grammar, consider moving from regex to a parser generator, like [Yapps](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent `re.compile("%[\+\/\-\*]%").split(formula)` from dropping the `%` characters by using lookarounds:

```
re.compile(r"(?<=%)[+/*-](?=%)").split(formula)
```

Another solution would be to split on `[+/*-]` but only if followed by an even number of `%` characters:

```
re.split(r'[+*/-](?=(?:(?:[^%]*%){2})*$)', formula)
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Never heard of the lookaround term before. Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: A little modification would also preserve the signs that were used for splitting: `r"(?<=%)([+/*-])(?=%)"`

Answer (score 0):

A 2-step solution:

```
import re

tempList = re.split("(\-|\+|\/|\*)(?=%)",'%abc-def%+%hij-klm%/%opq+rst%-%uvw-xyz%')

finalList = [x for x in tempList if "%" in x]

['%abc-def%', '%hij-klm%', '%opq+rst%', '%uvw-xyz%']
```

I hope this helps.